# repository - GIMP version 2.10

Tags: gimp

The Ubuntu Synaptic Package Manager show GIMP v 2.8 as the latest version and version 2.10 was release a couple of days ago. When do you expect GIMP v2.10 to be in the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: For stability reasons, most programs aren't really updated until the newer version of the program appears in a newer version of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 18.10 will probably have it.

Comment: Also looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gimp it shows as being in 'universe' (for Xenial-Bionic) meaning its up the community to test & package it. It may however appear earliest in the form of a snap  `snap find gimp` (shows only the same version found in Bionic currently)

Answer (score 1):

The version which you ask for was not available on feature freeze of 18.04 and will however maybe make it into 18.10. However for older versions of Ubuntu and 18.04 you can get this version of GIMP from a PPA. Follow the below steps to get it:

```bsh
sudo apt remove --purge gimp
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt update # Beginning with 18.04 this step can be omitted
sudo apt install gimp
```

This gives you as of time I'm writing this 2.10. This PPA is well maintained.

<sub>I'm not afilliated with this PPA in any form.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can install Gimp on Ubuntu using the official [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) app. Firstly install flatpak support.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Then

```
flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

and follow the instructions.

to run flatpaks you have to execute

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

If you want, you can create a .desktop file as a launcher. E.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=GNU image manipulation programm
Comment=GNU image manipulation programm
Exec=flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=gimp
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=gimp
Name=gimp
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Answer (score 1):

On [www.gimp.org](http://www.gimp.org), they recommend installing the flatpak of gimp 2.10 for Linux systems. This is not especially endorsed by ubuntu, maybe because ubuntu would rather favor their own snap format over flatpak. However, to date there is only gimp 2.8 available as a snap from ubuntu.

Anyway, with 18.04  it works perfectly for me: `sudo apt-get install flatpak` from ubuntu repo, and follow the instructions on www.gimp.org:   `flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref`

Or, after installing flatpak do `sudo apt-get install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak` to integrate flatpak with gnome-software, then you can use the flatpak [download link](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) on gimp.org.
That way you could also search for gimp in "Ubuntu Software" - it will bring up the flatpak download next to the classical gimp 2.8 download from the ubuntu repo.

Answer (score 1):

### GIMP from Snap

You can get GIMP 2.10 from the snap, but you will want to first uninstall your current version of GIMP.  You know, the one you probably got from the repositories.

1st:

```
sudo apt remove gimp --purge
```

then:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

After that you will most likely want to give the GIMP snap access to removable-media, so you type this in a terminal:

```
sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media :removable-media
```

Snap is nice because the developers can push the newest stable version once it is ready, and you don't have to wait around for Ubuntu to give it their blessing.  Just a few weeks ago the Snap was version 2.8.xx (I believe), and then suddenly it was 2.10!  I'm not complaining at all, as I needed a newer version so I can try to get the Darktable plugin to work in GIMP.