# Gimp "Could not interpret PostScript file"

Tags: gimp

When I try open an `.eps` file in Gimp, I get: `Could not interpret PostScript file '(path to file)'`. I have searched for answers, but all I find is solutions for Windows. They all concerns Ghostscript, which I have installed:

```
$ ghostscript --version
9.22
```

I run Ubuntu 18.04 and Gimp 2.10.6.

Comment: I suspect you installed Gimp 2.10.6 as a snap version (Does it say "Snap store" in Software Manager)? If yes, then we are facing another limitation/issue of the Snap format.

Comment: Ooh, snap! That is indeed the case! I guess I need to uninstall that version and install it with apt instead... Many thanks @vanadium

Comment: Just reinstalled with apt and I confirm that it is working. Snap really has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Gimp 2.10.6 in Ubuntu 18.04 using the software center, it will be installed as a snap package. Applications installed through snap are contained and are supposed to pack all their own dependencies. A solution at the level of the snap package is probably in the hands of the package maintainer.

To avoid this issue, install Gimp through the regular repositories. The version that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 is the older 2.8 version. You can install a newer version [by adding a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031480/repository-gimp-version-2-10).